# Creating an Array of unknown type

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have an object which I must validate values off the problem, some of the attributes of the Objects are arrays of custom objects. Such that it will involve some boring down into the individual elements of the array. Excuting the getters for each element such as:

```
AttribGrp[] x =  Object.getAttribGrp()
x[i].getSomeValue()
```

It is this I need to get to. I have been extracted the data using an Enum with the list of 
the attributes In the following manner.

```
public String getAttribValueAsString(MethodEnum attribName) 
{
    String attribValue = null;
    Object value = getAttrib(attribName.toString());

    if (value != null)
        attribValue = value.toString();

    return attribValue;
}
```

calling:

```
    private Object invoke(String methodName, Object newValue)
{
    Object value = null;
    try
    {
        methodInvoker.setTargetMethod(methodName);

        if (newValue != null)
            methodInvoker.setArguments(new Object[]{newValue});
        else
            methodInvoker.setArguments(new Object[]{});             

        methodInvoker.prepare();
        value = methodInvoker.invoke();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Method invocation failed. " + e.getMessage(),e);
    }
    catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Method invocation failed. " + e.getMessage(),e);
    }
    catch (InvocationTargetException e)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Method invocation failed. " + e.getMessage(),e);
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Method invocation failed. " + e.getMessage(),e);
    }
    return value;
}
```

I will be working with a number of arrays of different types and of different values within the arrays. I want to create a method as follows.

```
    public Object getAttribArray(RIORepeatingGrpEnum repeatingGrp)
{
        repeatingGrp[] grp = null;
              Object grpVal = getAttrib(repeatingGrp.toString());
              if(grp != null)
                   grp = (repeatingGrp[]) grpVal;

              return grp;
}
```

This is giving me multiple errors mainly concerned with repeatingGrp[]. The array type should be the same name as enum. Is it possible to create a method like this that will create an array of non defined type?

Comment: I don't understand "repeatingGrp[]" you are treating it as a type, but repeatingGrp is a variable name...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Arrays of Generic Types in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428145/creating-arrays-of-generic-types-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have arrays of unknown types, use generics:

```
 public <T> T[] getAttribArray(Class<T> repeatingGrpClass)
 {
    //get the attribute based on the class (which you might get based on the enum for example)
    return (T[]) getAttrib( repeatingGrpClass.getName() ); //note that you might want to use the class object instead of its name here
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot use a variable (`repeatingGrp`) as a type.

There are ways to do "dynamic" casting, but these wouldn't help you.  The return type of `getAttribArray` is `Object`, which would defeat the point of casting to a particular type.

And even if you could fix that, it's still not clear what you could do with this mechanism.  What do you want to be able to do with the result of `getAttribArray()`?

Comment: OK I can get that. But say I was able to have the return type: repeatGrp[] which exists within the incoming object.

Comment: @Will: But then what?  What would you then do with the result?

Comment: I would pass over the array calling the various getter methods on each element to extract the values and validate them.

Comment: @Will: Why not do that with polymorphism?  Derive all your types from a common base class (or interface), and then have that base-class/interface declare a `validate()` method.

Comment: I'm using a rules engine for the rules. It is this engine that is calling this code. I'm declaring the different types available via RIORepeatingGrpEnum granted that is just the names since that way the arrays can be extracted when it runs the get RIORepeatingGrpEnum

Comment: @Will: Ok, but polymorphism is the solution here.  If you are constrained by third-party code, you will need to edit your question to make these constraints clear.

Comment: Why would I need polymorphism if I could extract the correct array based on the input enum. Then from that Enum execute the associated getters? What benefit with Polymorphism bring?

Comment: @Will: As you have found, this is harder than it sounds.  Polymorphism exists to eliminate the need to do all of this manually.

Answer (score 0):

As Oli Charlesworth points out, you can not use the variable name to cast.  For a generic type, you will have to cast to `Object` or `Object[]`.

Also the `Object` -> `Object[]` cast looks illegal.  You probably just want a straight cast like so:

```
public Object[] getAttribArray(RIORepeatingGrpEnum repeatingGrp)
{
    Object[] grp = (Object[])getAttrib(repeatingGrp.toString());
    return grp;
}
```

Comment: You still have that Object -> Object[] cast in the return statement :)